# `initialize': undefined method `gauge' (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

Does anyone know why Im getting this error: `initialize': undefined method`gauge' for # (NoMethodError)?! I mean Im using the attr_accessor for the getters and setters for gauge but still it says that I have not declared it. I have below posted a fragment of the code. Thanks in advance.

```
class ParkingLotGuest < Guest

attr_accessor :gauge, :electricity_bill, :type_of_stay  

def initialize (name, address, phone, arrival, lives_where, type_of_stay, guest_wishes_electricity)
    super(name, address, phone, arrival, lives_where)
    @type_of_stay = type_of_stay
    @electricity_bill = 0 
    @gauge = 0;
    if (guest_wishes_electricity[0,1] == "j")
        @gauge = lives_where.gauge
    end
end
```

Here is the code form the parking_lot class:

```
class Parking_Lot

attr_accessor :nr
    attr_accessor :gauge
attr_reader :electricity_meter

# Initiates a new caravan plot with the number nr and a electricity meter between
# 2000 och 4000.
def initialize (nr)
    @nr = nr
            @gauge = gauge
    @electricity_meter = 4000-rand(2000)
end

# increases the electricity meter for use with a random amount between 
# 10-80 kWh per 24 h.
def increase_meter(days)
    generatedUse = (10+rand(70))*days
    puts "Increases the meter with " + generatedUse.to_s + " kWh."
    @electricity_meter += generatedUse
end

# Returns a string representation of the camping plot.
def to_s

  "Plot #{@nr+1} Electricity meter: #{@electricity_meter} kWh"

end 
end
```

Code from the camping class.

```
@staticGuests = Array[   
    ParkingLotGuest.new("Logan Howlett", "Tokyo", "07484822", 1, @parking_lots[0], "Husvagn", "j", @gauge), 
    ParkingLotGuest.new("Scott Summers",    "Chicago", "8908332", 2, @parking_lots[1], "Husbil", "j", @gauge),
  ParkingLotGuest.new("Hank Moody",     "Boston", "908490590",23, @parking_lots[2], "Tält", "n", @gauge),
  CabinGuest.new("Jean Grey", "Detroit", "48058221", 4, @parking_lots[3]['Wolverine']),
  CabinGuest.new("Charles Xavier",  "Washington DC", "019204822", 5, @parking_lots[4]['Thanos'])
]
```

Comment: Can you paste your exact error? Which line is it happening on, 9 or 11?

Comment: Maybe the error is in @gauge = lives_where.gauge

Comment: The error is on @gauge = lives_where.gauge. It seems as it after the if statement does not recognize @gauge. I thought that the fact that I have it as a part of the attr_accessor means that it is initialized. Am I mistaken?! Thanks. BTW here is the exact error: ./guest.rb:58:in `initialize': undefined method `gauge' for #<Parking_Lot:0x10017c860 @electricity_meter=3622, @nr=0> (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 1):

look at the error more carefully:

```
undefined method `gauge' for #<Parking_Lot:0x10017c860 @electricity_meter=3622, @nr=0> (NoMethodError)
```

What this is saying is that an instance of `Parking_Lot` received a method call for a method named `gauge`, and it didn't have a `gauge` method.

In this line, there is only one method call.

```
@gauge = lives_where.gauge
```

`@gauge = ...` assigns directly to the instance variable `@gauge`, bypassing the setter method, so it's not that.

`lives_where.gauge` is probably what is complaining. Is `lives_where` a `Parking_Lot`?

Comment: thanks for the helpful feedback. I see what you mean. Ill post some more code above form the parking_lot class...can it be form there?!

Comment: Yes, the Parking_Lot class needs to have a gauge method for the ParkingLotGuest's initialize to work. It's calling gauge on a Parking_Lot, but Parking_Lots don't have gauges in the code you posted.

Comment: Also, usually you don't put underscores in class names, so  Parking_Lot would usually look like ParkingLot

Comment: I tried it put it gives me the same error?! I have pasted the code above. If you have any clues please do tell. i also pasted a bit form the camping class were ParkingLotGuest are generated by the program, maybe there is something wrong there? Thanks a lot for your feedback.